# How does SQS FIFO ensure exactly once processing?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-sqs, fifo

SQS FIFO guarantees that it will process a message from a queue exactly once. I am wondering what is the core logic behind it. How does it process a message exactly once from the queue in a distributed environment when thousands of transaction are happening. I just wanted to know the basic architecture and design principles. So I think someone who worked one such architecture could really give some insights.

Answer (score 4):

According to the [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSSimpleQueueService/latest/SQSDeveloperGuide/FIFO-queues.html), the guarantee is that it won't let the same message be submitted to the queue in a 5 minute window. Message equality is defined by either body hash or an id you pass when submitting.

> Unlike standard queues, FIFO queues don't introduce duplicate messages. FIFO queues help you avoid sending duplicates to a queue. If you retry the `SendMessage` action within the 5-minute deduplication interval, Amazon SQS doesn't introduce any duplicates into the queue.

So it sounds to me like they have a central hash table of hashes/ids, they check against it for every new message, and automatically remove hashes/ids older than 5 minutes. You can use Redis with TTL to implement that pretty easily.

I couldn't find any information about the scalability of this but it sounds like it's more expensive to scale than normal queues, judging by the added TPS (transactions per second) limits.

Comment: You have understated the guarantee, which includes in-order delivery of the non-duplicated messages.  Between that and the 300 TPS limit, it seems evident that they must be using some kind of internal locking mechanism.